# How to print the contents of an array without creating anything on the stack?

Tags: c++, c, programming-languages

I was asked this question in an interview. I didn't know what to tell him. I asked him what's the solution but he refused to answer. I searched for it on google and I couldn't find it. Appreciate the help.

Comment: The question is pretty unclear. It's possible the interviewer was incompetent.

Comment: You should've asked "what do you even mean by that" rather than for the solution. If that was the actual question, there is no way to even know what they meant.

Comment: That was the actual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive, that this question was intended more to check your understanding of internal program working (stack usage, allocation/deallocation, etc). Lets consider your question:

> How to print the contents of an array without creating anything on the
>   stack?

What exactly that means? Should the program stack be in the same state after printing? In that case just use a function to print stack contents, it will return the stack to the same state. If your interviewer means, that there should be no changes on the stack altogether, it is very difficult, and perhaps not possible on many platforms. This requirement means, that you could not use any printing function from the standard C/C++ library, because any call will alter the stack. You could create working code, that will not affect stack memory in the some older OS (like MS DOS for example) by the direct writing to the video buffer, using only the procesor registers. Any modern OS will prevent that and would require some API call, which will make initial requirement quite impossible.

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 : Interviewer was an idiot

Option 2 : Question was a test of character.

I always like to ask an "impossible" question to see if the interviewee will try of B.S. me or if they will admit they don't know and that they would try to find the answer and ask for help if need be